# AngularJS non-ascii query parameter

Tags: angularjs, url, unicode, non-ascii-characters

I've run into a issue where a redirect to an AngularJS page can contain non-ascii characters as a query parameter.

When the query contains `/?id=test%F6test` the value instantly turns into `/?id=undefined` 
(by Angular I presume).

Is there a nice way around this?

Comment: i think the variable is getting undefined, if you are sure variable is containing the value and available then try urlencode the variable before appending to query.

Comment: @atulquest93 the character is encoded, %F6 is a swedish ö character not too uncommonly used in names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Unicode code point needs to encoded into [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

For [code point `\u00F6`,](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00f6/index.htm)  encode it as `%C3%B6`

```js
console.log(window.encodeURI("testötest"));
console.log(window.encodeURI('\u00F6'));
```

`%F6` must never appear in a valid UTF-8 sequence.

Comment: Ok, apparently there are some issues on the source side then. I assumed (never should have) that they encoded it correctly.